# Need an Idiomatic expression of the English language

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-request

I need an idiom

> रस्सी जल गयी लेकिन उसकी बल नहीं गयी

literal translation

> The rope burnt but its strength didn't vanish!

We use this expression in Hindi for anyone's arrogance. despite kneeling down and no status remaining, they didn't become unconceited and the attitude didn't vanish too!

Comment: It may be *Old habits die hard.*

Comment: Another equivalent may be *A leopard cannot change its spots*

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder, Neither of both suits here . we use this 'A leopard cannot change its spots  , when we are unable to change our behaviors that we are used to .

Answer (score 1):

The closest current idiomatic phrase I can think of is "plaster saint". This phrase once meant: "Someone without human failings."

However, probably since no human is actually without failings, it now used more sarcastically and has come to mean: "A person who makes a show of being without moral faults or human weakness, especially in a hypocritical way."